# Character Format in php

Tags: php, html, character-reference

Sorry I can’t log in claim ID is having server issues (im normally Arthur Gibbs)

Data from my database currently outputs this when there are strange charecters...

This is just a example

What I get: `De&#8730;ilscrat™`
What I want: `De√ilscrat™`

It seems that some characters are being translated into character code by the other guys system..

So what I want to know is:

Is there a function that will expand charecter codes within a string?

Turning `FUNCTION(De&#8730;ilscrat™)`   >>>  `De√ilscrat™`.

Comment: what you get and what you want seems identical on my machine.

Comment: @cemkalyoncu : this is because HTML entities are not escaped by SO, and interpreted by your browser. I edited the OP to add "code" formating, to prevent that interpretation.

Answer (score 6):

This `&#8730;` stuff looks like an HTML entity ; so, let's try de-entitying it...

This can be done using the [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) function, that's provided by PHP.

For instance, with the string you provided, here's a sample of code :

```
// So the browser interprets the correct charsert
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$input = 'De&#8730;ilscrat™';
$output = html_entity_decode($input, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');

var_dump($input, $output);
```

And the output I'm getting is this one :

```
string 'De&#8730;ilscrat™' (length=19)
string 'De√ilscrat™' (length=15)
```

*(First one is the original version, and second one is the "decoded" version)*

So, it seems to do the trick ;-)

Comment: Didn’t know that `html_entity_decode` decodes both numeric and entity character references. The name rather implies that only the latter is supported.

Comment: @Gumbo : I wasn't sure about it either -- but it seems to decode them fine, from the test I did (or maybe I got lucky ^^ )